# How can I modify a graphQL query based off of the variable passed to it?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have built this query to request data from the Pokeapi graphQL server here
https://beta.pokeapi.co/graphql/console/

```
query getPokemon (
  $typesList: [Int!],
)  {
  pokemon_v2_pokemon(
    where: { 
      pokemon_v2_pokemontypes: { type_id: { _in: $typesList } }
    }
  ) {
    id
    name
    pokemon_v2_pokemontypes {
      type_id
      pokemon_v2_type {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I modify the query to return all results when the `$typesList` list is empty? I would like the query to return a filtered results list when `$typesList` has a list of ids, but it should return all values when the `$typesList` list is empty.

Is this something that is possible in graphQL?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you controlled the server you could write the resolver to function in the manner you're looking for but since you don't your only option is to wrap your use of the query with something that sets the default `typesList` variable to all possible types.